# Can I use Auth method in blade to show certain options in the select?

Tags: laravel

I would like to know if it is possible use a blade directive to make some custom options. I want when the admin is authenticated appears all users, and if it is a student, the options available reduces to one.

```html
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('course_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id">
            <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
            @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
                <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                    {{ $user }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('course_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
@if( auth()->user()->type == 'admin' )
    <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
    @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $user }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
@else
    // Here I just need the user_id of the guest
@endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: `"Here I just need the user_id of the guest"`  Means user is authenticated?

Comment: If authenticated then use `auth()->user()->id`

Comment: Hi Amit. What I need is a select with only one option (the student, for example, Amit Senjaliya). In this option I just want to show the user name, but in the value of the select I need the user_id (for example, 1), because It will be the way in which the register will make in the database.

Comment: @Noel is student authenticated?? `user_id` comes from user table??

Comment: user_id is an attribute in the Registered_Course model which is a foreign key and is related to the User Model. Both models has a relation in the models to access the other one. I can access in other views to some attributes from user from Registered_Course, but in this case, It is impossible without use a select.

Comment: you want something like `@else
<option value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id) == auth()->user()->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ auth()->user()->name }}
        </option>
   
@endif`

Answer (score 1):

If you use different guards, you can do like this:

`@auth('admin')`

Otherwise you can make your own blade directives.

Do something like this in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::if('admin', function () {
        return (auth()->user()->type == 'admin') ? true : false;
    });
}
```

Then in your blade file:

```
@admin
    // Code...
@else
    // Code...
@endadmin
```

You can also pass a value to the directive like this: `function ($userType)`

And then in blade: `@admin(auth()->user()->type)`

Comment: Thanks. I am a begginer in Laravel. I have no idea what it is providers, I need to read some documentation about it. But is it possible to use the if/end without use Providers?